# Android: Can any launch icon be used, as long as it's 48x48 png?

Tags: android

I'm finally ready to upload my Android app to the market. I didn't create a fancy icon like it shows at the android developer site. I just made an image that I liked and made it 48x48 png. Will that be ok?

Comment: No, didn't try to upload yet. I'm going to try to design an icon close to the android standards using the 'Inkscape' software.

Answer (score 2):

In general yes, there aren't Apple style guidelines in place. However, ugly icons will cause most people to quickly skip over your application. If you couldn't be bothered to make a good icon, why would you have a good application?

Comment: A good point, thank you. BUT, I have seen some great apps (both mobile and desktop) carry some very simplistic icons and then some bad apps having a great looking one. I don't judged an app by its icon (nor a book by its cover) and I have never let an icon stop me from checking out an app.

Comment: @Allan: Simplistic doesn't necessarily imply ugly.